# Clean up the [grab] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [grab](/questions/tagged/grab) serves no purpose. I suggest the questions be cleaned up and the tag be burninated.

See slugster's answer below for specific cleanup suggestions.

Comment: Go get my burninator toolkit on stackapps.com.  Apparently there are some valid questions with the tag (appears to be a python library for website scraping).  Most are BS, however.  Full burnination is probably not viable.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest not.

There are current 52 questions with this tag. While some of them can simply have the tag removed, some of them also need to be retagged and/or have extra work done on them. If you have sufficient privileges then this sort of clean up is encouraged and can earn you some shiny badges. If you don't have sufficient reputation then you can achieve this with suggested edits (which earn you more rep).

Here are some examples of questions on that list that require extra attention:

- [How to collect data from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549910/how-to-collect-data-from-a-website): [grab](/questions/tagged/grab) -> [data-retrieval](/questions/tagged/data-retrieval)
- [How to grab video frame from hardware overlay (not from my app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164783/how-to-grab-video-frame-from-hardware-overlay-not-from-my-app): [grab](/questions/tagged/grab) -> [frame-grab](/questions/tagged/frame-grab)
- [How does google collect movie showtimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869784/how-does-google-collect-movie-showtimes): needs to be closed and deleted
- [C# Grab details from web page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4408213/109702): needs tag removed from title, [grab](/questions/tagged/grab) -> [automation](/questions/tagged/automation)

@Will also has a valid point, you need to ensure there isn't a valid use of the tag due to a third party library/API, in which case the tag can stay but the appropriate language and API tags also need to be added.